# Laravel Multi Auth from more than two tables

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.6

I want to write a web service with laravel
I am trying to authenticate **users** and **admin** form `users` table and `admins` table respectively.
In this web service, user and admin authentication are different.
Authentication admins by `email` & users by `phone number`.Admins access Admin Panel by `Web` routes and users use `API` routes.
As I know `Auth::attempt` is used to authenticate `admins` from `admins` table, but I want to authenticate another users from `users` table and admin from `admin` table.
**Can anyone explain Multi Auth from more than two tables with example??**

> I know that `Auth::attempt` is used to authenticate `users` from users table but I changed the name.

What I have done so far
**Guards**
config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

**Providers**

```
'providers' => [
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],
```

**Routes**
web.php (admins)

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'] , function (){

    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'LoginController@login');
    $this->get('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    $this->post('password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset');
});
```

api.php (users)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'android/v1' , 'namespace' => 'Api\Android\v1'] , function (){
    $this->post('login' , 'UserController@login');
    $this->post('register' , 'UserController@register');
});
```

**UserController**
api/android/v1/UserController.php

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $validData = $this->validate($request, [
        'mobile' => 'required|exists:users',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);
    if(! auth()->attempt($validData)) {
        return response([
            'data' => 'data not true',
            'status' => 'error'
        ],403);
    }

    return new UserResource(auth()->user());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation would be
Have different controllers for your Admins and your Users, then you can specify why is the guard that you are going use to handle the request.